# How to add "name" attribute to a links in sidebar

Tags: wordpress

I need to add "name" attribute to all links in the sidebar. 
For example;

Before

```
<li id="menu-item-573" class="gallery-menu-top menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-573"><a href="#">WEDDINGS</a></li>
```

After

```
<li id="menu-item-573" class="gallery-menu-top menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-573"><a name="Weddings" href="#">WEDDINGS</a></li>
```

**name="Weddings"**

Comment: maybe this should be asked here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score -1):

If you can add this class to the side menu UL "sidebar";
and the value of the name attribute is always going to match the content of the link then this should work:

```
 $('.sidebar a').each(function(i, item){   
     var value = item.textContent;        
      $(item).attr('name', value );            
  });
```

Here's a working example = http://jsfiddle.net/4SNv4/ -

EDIT sorry just noticed this is a word press question: so you probably dont have the ability to do the above.